# Catch touched inside UIWebView displayed in an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm developing an iOS app which used for one view an UITableView.
I want to resize the cell when they are touched from a default size (constant) to their real size (stored in a tab).

I tried first to place this code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function but this function is never called ...

I look around some tutorial and my class already has this : 
- My class extends UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
- In the ViewDidLoad I've this code :

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
```

I may know where does the problem comes from. My UITableView is grouped and is composed of one cell per section.
Each cell is a custom cell containing an UIWebView inside. To sum up : 
My view > tableView > MyCellCustom > MyWebViewCustom

I read that the touched event may have been "eaten" by the WebView. How to know if the problems comes from that ? How to avoid this ?

And by the way, I'm not even sure that the problem comes from this. I just feel frustrated because I used `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so often and I never encounter that kind of troubles.

Then, I tried to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to all my UIWebView like this :

```
let indicationTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
indicationTap.delegate = self
indicationTap.addTarget(self, action: "SingleTap:")
indicationTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
indicationTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
self.indication.webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(indicationTap)
```

And then this function :

```
func SingleTap(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("touch detected")
}
```

But it still not working ...
I don't know what's wrong and what is the best way to handle touch-event inside UIWebView.

Thank you in advance for your answer, 
Have a nice day.
Tom.

Comment: hi tom if it is possible remove user interaction to webview

Comment: `addGestureRecognizer` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for each web view to see whether it's the problem.

Comment: Hi, I understand your problem. Touch ignore due to webview. Take a tap gesture and add this tap gesture to the webview in every cell. Then you can handle tap on webview. For better understanding see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734682/how-to-detect-touch-on-uiwebview)

Comment: I try to add the TapGestureRecognizer but it didn't work neither ...
I've update my question to let you see what I did

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain the touch event within your `UIWebView` and also have the touch event trigger the row selection, you should wrap your `UIWebView` inside a subclass of `UIView` and then use that inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of your `UITableView`.

This should help: [How to Get webview from UITableView didselectrowatindexpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322728/how-to-get-webview-from-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath)

Comment: I add "self.userInteractionEnabled = false" inside the init method of my UIWebView class and the problem is still present.

And actually I need to keep the userInteraction enabled because I have feature base on the HTML which is loaded inside ...

Comment: @TomGiraudet My edited answer may be more helpful in this situation.

Comment: My WebView is already wrapped inside a subclass of UITableViewCell